# Applied filter to string, not to characters

Tags: scala

Starting with Scala. I am trying to code this:

```
def getPortNamePart(portName: String) {

  val maybePortName = portName.filter(_.trim.length > 0)
  val portNamePart = maybePortName.map(portName => s"_$portName").getOrElse("")
}

println(getPortNamePart("something"))   // expected "something"
println(getPortNamePart(""))            // expected ""
println(getPortNamePart("   "))         // expected ""
```

But I get:

:10: error: value trim is not a member of Char
             val maybePortName = portName.filter(_.trim.length > 0)

Which tells me that the filter is being applied to the each character of the string.

But I do not want that, I want the filter to be applied to the string. How can I code my filtering so that it happens at the string level?

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve:

```
def getPortNamePart(portName: String) =
  Option(portName).filter(_.trim.length > 0).map(portName => s"_$portName").getOrElse("")
```

`filter` works on exactly the same collection you applied it to (and `String` can be thought of as a collection of chars). So if you want to get `Option` on `String` filtering, you need to wrap it with Option first.

Comment: Create a option only to be able to use a filter when a `if` would do just fine doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: I would probably use `if` myself, but I personally hate answers like `scrap your code and do it in a completely different way cause it is better` without any additional details.  First, "better" is a subjective thing. Second, next time I will have the same issue, that "better" way, might not apply, and I would have to ask the very same question again because the answer did not address that issue.

Comment: Well, your answer is doing it in a completely different way. The issue is that to achieve what the OP want, filter won't work.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. Since I am not yet confident enough with Scala, I want to stick to the current style of the existing codebase as much as possible, and this satisfies that requirement. I do not understand though what `Option` does: I thought it was a syntax helper to mark optional arguments, which have value `null` (or the Scala equivalent) if not passed. But it seems you can also use `Option` in normal code, not only for arguments. What does it do?

Comment: It's basically a container that can hold at most 1 value. You can use if for handling optional parameters/return values, but also use it as such container with all consequences: mapping, filtering, for-comprehension, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That's how filter works over strings. What you want is:

```
if(portName.trim.length>0) portName else ""
```

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case you don't need any functional constructs. Do it with simple if .. else statements